# jquery addClass and removeClass with setInterval

Tags: jquery, ajax, setinterval, addclass, removeclass

I want to change class name every 3 seconds. Bu it doesn't work. How can I do this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        function moveClass(){
            var x = $('.liveEvents');
            x.removeClass('liveEvents');
            x.addClass('liveEventsActive');
            x.removeClass('liveEventsActive');
            x.addClass('liveEvents');
       }

        setInterval(moveClass, 3000); 
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this in one line. Use [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/):

```
setInterval(function(){$('.liveEvents').toggleClass('liveEventsActive')}, 3000);
```

If you do your CSS correctly, you don't need to remove the `liveEvents` class. Just make the `liveEventsActive` class overwrite what you need.

Comment: i think this will toggle liveEventsActive class, not liveEvents, am i wrong

Comment: You are correct, but with the proper CSS declarations in the "liveEventsActive" class you don't need to.

Answer (score 4):

You're doing four things every time the function runs, which essentially takes you back to your start state:

- Remove class `liveEvents`
- Add class `liveEventsActive`
- Remove class `liveEventsActive`
- Add class `liveEvents`

You want to toggle those two classes on/off, so take a look at the [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) function. You'll also need two selectors, one to select elements with the `liveEvents` class and one to select elements with the `liveEventsActive` class.

Answer (score 4):

With your code, the whole function is executed every 3 seconds. The add/remove class happens in one block and you obvisouly cannot see the difference.

jQuery has a [.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) method that will add/remove the specified class accordingly:

```
function moveClass() {
    $('.liveEvents')
        .toggleClass('liveEventsActive');
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/8GqXv/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function moveClass(){
        $( ".liveEvents" ).switchClass( "liveEvents", "liveEventsActive", 1000);
        $( ".liveEventsActive" ).switchClass( "liveEventsActive", "liveEvents", 1000 );
   }

    setInterval(moveClass, 3000); 
    return false;
});
```

this will swap your classes using transitions, hope this will help