# setInterval is not adding .addClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a CSS marquee that displays values from a DB. After x minutes it refreshes and new data is pulled. The colors change based on their numerical value (if x < 50000 make it red ...etc).

My issue is once my `setInterval` runs the data is updated but the color classes don't get added. Any idea why? I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9099263/jquery-addclass-and-removeclass-with-setinterval) and changed my remove/add class to a toggle but it was the same issue, the toggle wasn't being called after the initial run.

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setColors();
    setInterval(function () { 
        $('.marquee').addClass("paused"); 
        $('.marquee').load('/Home/GetMarquee'); 
        setColors(); 
        $('.marquee').removeClass("paused"); 
    }, 30000);
});

function setColors() {
    $('.totalSales').each(function () {

        var final = $(this).text();

        //removes all the pervious classes
        $(this).removeClass('ok');
        $(this).removeClass('down');
        $(this).removeClass('up');

        if (final > 100000) {
            $(this).addClass('up');
        } else if (final < 50000) {
            $(this).addClass('down');
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('ok');
        }
    });
}
```

**Razor HTML**

```
<div class="marquee">
    <span>
        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.tickerData.Count(); i++)
        {
            <span class="totalSales">
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.tickerData[i].GroupName): @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.tickerData[i].Sales).....
            </span>
        }        
    </span>
</div>
```

**CSS Colors**

```
.down {
    color:#AB2218;
}
.up {
    color: #4F692A;
}
.ok {
     color:#FABF03;
}
```

**CSS Marquee**

```
.marquee {
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color:black;
    border: 1px black solid;
    font-size:50px;

    -webkit-animation: marquee 30s linear infinite alternate;
        animation: marquee 30s linear infinite;
}
.paused {
    animation-play-state: paused;
}

.marquee span {
    display: inline-block;
    text-indent: 0;
}


/* Make it move */
@keyframes marquee {
    0%   { text-indent: 17.5em }
    100% { text-indent: -57.5em }
}
@-webkit-keyframes marquee{
    0%   { text-indent: 17.5em }
    100% { text-indent: -57.5em }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.load` is an async ajax function, so it doesn't block until it finishes, and the class adding and removing happens too quickly to notice. Try using the `.load` callback:

```
setInterval(function () { 
    $('.marquee').addClass("paused"); 
    $('.marquee').load('/Home/GetMarquee', function() { 
        setColors(); 
        $('.marquee').removeClass("paused");
    }); 
}, 30000);
```